# creating Pcollection from json string input

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-unittest, dataflow

I am trying to create a unit test for my Dataflow code. However, I am getting error while creating pcollection using beam.create().

In the original function, I am using json.loads(element) which takes json string as input and gives the dictionary as o/p.

Test code:

def test(self):

```
input = '{"name": "xyz"}'
expected_output = {'name': 'xyz'}
input_string = p | beam.create(input) #pipeline object is already defined as p
output = input_string | beam.pardo(_splitdata) #calling the original function here
assert_that(output,equal_to(expected_output))
```

Errors :

1. beam.create() is not taking string as input. It just takes iterables and If I make input as suppose a list or any other iterable then json.loads() as part of _splitdata() expects the json object just as str.

How do I resolve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got into similar scenario today, here is my solution:

```
import apache_beam as beam

data = [
          {
              'id': 1,  
              'name': 'abc',
          },
          {
              'id': 2, 
              'name': 'xyz'
          }
      ]

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  plant_details = (
      pipeline
      | 'Read Input Data' >> beam.Create(data)
      | beam.Map(print))
```

Output:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'abc'}
{'id': 2, 'name': 'xyz'}
```